# Angular2 Component Caching

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there any kind of caching of destroyed components? My app goes slow as a load or change data, even I render only few components in view. in each routing I'm getting new data, consider it is a grid and I'm changing data as per routing, but the app goes slow after 3-4 navigation. I found change detection tales more time

Comment: Don't measure in `devMode`. Switch to `prodMode` instead. Also don't measure when TS is built on-the-fly. Create a deployable and then measure performance.

Comment: I have seen it that navigation becomes slow after a few route changes. Especially in IE. This is some bug in Angular or IE or both but I doubt it is related to component loading.

Comment: is IE normally slow in rendering angular components?

Comment: No, there is an issue that IE becomes slow after some routerLink clicks. That doesn't mean rendering components is slow.